# Replace using regexp and conserving the result

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I would like to replace every ' by - when the ' is between 2 letters :

[a-zA-Z]'[a-zA-Z]
by 
[a-zA-Z]-[a-zA-Z]

example :
 "N'Guyen" => "N-Guyen"

but I get "-uyen"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Find what: `([a-zA-Z])'([a-zA-Z])`

Replace with: `\1-\2`.

The `\1` and `\2` refer to the capture groups `([a-zA-Z])` and `([a-zA-Z])` respectively.

Comment: @Hystic: Please make sure that in the `Replace` tab, you have the `Regular expression` check box marked (it should be under `Search Mode`).

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to replace only one character, not all the words before and after. So you need to use positive lookbehind and lookahead assertsions:`(?<=[a-zA-Z])'(?=[a-zA-Z])` replace by `-`

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/kU0xV0/1

Comment: No, it is not better, it is only a different way to do the same thing. Also, lookarounds are more expensive than capture groups (they take slightly more time, but if there's a lot to replace, the delay becomes increasingly significant).